# Maven surefire plugin fork mode

Tags: maven-2, surefire, fork

By default maven surefile plugin run tests in isolated (forked) environment. You can override this behavior with following configuration:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

If you need to debug your tests you should to use this configuration snippet. Or you could simply run maven build the following way:

```
$ mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug tests
```

This will starts a debugger on the port 5005.

My question is: what benefits have forking strategy and why is chosen as a default strategy for maven build? Isn't nonforking strategy is more straightforward and therefore should be used as default (maven is convention over configuration tool, right)?

Comment: Of note, `forkMode` is now deprecated, [reuseForks](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reuseForks) should be used instead

Comment: Actually I think `forkCount=0` is what should be used now to disable new JVMs launching.  http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#forkCount

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> My question is: what benefits have forking strategy and why is chosen as a default strategy for maven build?

By default, Surefire forks your tests using a manifest-only JAR. IMO, the main advantages are that:

1. it provides an isolated environment with a somehow "correct" classpath.
2. it protects the maven process itself (which is a good thing, especially *if Maven is running embedded in your IDE*).

> Isn't nonforking strategy is more straightforward and therefore should be used as default?

Straightforward for what? Easy debugging inside an IDE? I believe that was not the initial intention (and I prefer to connect a remote debugger if the need arises and to keep the main Maven process safe).

#### See also

- [Classloading and Forking in Maven Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html)

Comment: What does "forking a test" mean?

Comment: A fork is when a process executes a task in a new process rather than its own. In case of surefire, it means tests will be run in separate processes for maximum performance / concurrency. Sometimes you might want to tweak that or switch it off altogether (when debugging, for example).

Comment: well this makes testing in ide practically useless

Answer (score 1):

forking mode helps to load system classpath if it is set to "true" or "once".
But sometimes setting fork mode= true caues errors like "commmand line too long" or "there are test failures" if maven-surefire 2.5 plugin is used. To avoid this error its is recommended to ser forkmode=never whn using suefire plugin 2.5

Comment: I think this sort of error happens only on Windows, because of this OS have some limitations on command line length.