# Eclipse(STS) break breakpoint not hit using maven surefire plugin and scala ide

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I was wondering whether anyone could shed some light on this peculiar problem. I am using STS 3.2 (i.e. Eclipse 4.3 Kepler) with the Scala IDE and the Eclipse Maven plugin. The version of Maven I am using is Maven 3.0.5. I am using the maven surefire plugin version 2.4.3 and Scala version 2.10.2 . I have followed the instructions such as those provided here http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html and [Maven build debug in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598261/maven-build-debug-in-eclipse) however, however when I set break points in my JUnit scala tests, the break points are not being hit. I am not sure why this happening. Is there a problem with Eclipse Scala Maven and Maven Surefire??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have flexibility in your choice of IDEs then I'd switch to IntelliJ

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

I've had issues like this in the past with maven-eclipse and while they are solvable, Intellij supports maven natively.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. At the moment, we have to stick with Eclipse. We may be able to change IDEs but we want to exhaust all avenues with Eclipse before considering others.  Would up vote but I dont have enough points to do that! :-(