# Debugging maven projects with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven

Hello I'm trying to debug my Maven Projects (multi module project with parent pom) according this post:

Right click project

Debug as -> Maven build ...

In the goals field put -Dmaven.surefire.debug test

In the parameters put a new parameter called forkMode with a value of never
([Maven build debug in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598261/maven-build-debug-in-eclipse))

The maven build starts and after building all projects it stops. The application does not start and nothing happens.

Do I have to setup anything in the parent pom.xml?

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided is for debugging the maven build process, not the final application.

If you want to debug the application, you follow the standard procedures of configuring the JVM / app server to allow debug connections. You do not need to worry about maven at all.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)