# QAF- Code debug is not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, qaf

I am using https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-maven
project to run simple login scenario in eclipse. My debug point is not getting triggered when I run my simple scenario.

Note: I am not using testNG in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to run as maven test in debug mode. If so you should refer
[Maven build debug in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12598261/861594)
and other similar questions.

Adding `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` in goal worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Its working as expected. Tahnk you @user861594