# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test (default-test) on project smrr: There are test failures

Tags: java, netbeans-7, maven-plugin

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test
>   (default-test) on project smrr: There are test failures.
>
> Please refer to C:\Users\root\Downloads\smrr\target\surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results.
>   -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
>   Check Maven network proxy...
>
> ====================================

Anyone please solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven will try to install this plugin along with dependencies first time in .m2/repository folder, due proxy issues dependencies failing to download.
so,
Update the Maven project:

Steps:

Right-click on "project"
Go to "Maven" >> "Update"
Wait for all the changes to be applied
Commit the changes (if code is on repo)
Run

Also check the artifactid, groupid, version of plugins along with dependencies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13170860/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-10test

Comment: ((Right-click on "project" Go to "Maven" >> "Update" Wait for all the changes to be applied Commit the changes (if code is on repo) Run.)) sorry, I do not see maven in options ??

Comment: My steps are wrt to eclipse ide for M2e plugin, I am sure steps will workout in eclipse ide. I need to check the steps to followup for netbeans ide

Answer (score 2):

I too got this error when I was running *mvn test -Dtest=*. This error occurred because name of the *testclass* was incorrect. Once I fixed the name of the test class this error was fixed.

I feel this error occurs when the argument for -Dtest has no test cases to run.

I hope this helps you..

Comment: Thanks. I added the test classes from the sample program. It worked initially. But then started giving problem. So I deleted from my project as it was not required any more. Things started working