# Run unit/integration test(s) within a given process i.e. existing test server

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

**Problem statement**
How to invoke tests within a given test server(i.e. within the process)?

**Explanation**
We know that there is surefire plugin, but this uses `surefire:test` goal which runs unit tests in separate process. In my case, i need to run the tests within the existing process (pre-configured test server and required environment) to run test. In surefire plugin, there is configuration that has forkCount and reuseForks. If i use it with forkCount as 0, reuseForks true, still creates separate server and hence process. I simply want to avoid setup part for test.

**Update after Joe's comment saying it as duplicate** As my application usage SpringBoot, running `mvn clean install` build the project and execute tests. While executing tests, it creates server for each running test. Even though i used configuration given below, in console it shows same process id, but starting server every time. In my case i don't want to make server up for every test case, rather used pre-existing test server and the test should use that server.

**Configuration used**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven surefire plugin fork mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185850/maven-surefire-plugin-fork-mode)

Comment: @Joe thank you for the link. Yes some how i need that way, but not sure it will fulfill my whole requirement will do it and update the thread.

Comment: @Joe What way i can see that making forkcount 0, it usage same process id?

Comment: Could you please share the code for one of the tests? I'd expect it to share the server instance unless your configuration differs between tests or you use something like @DirtiesContext